# Проблема в шаблоне на моб версии сайта СSS

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile

буду признателен если подскажите как исправить шаблон для моб версии сайта. На мобильной версии под описанием продукта отсутствует фон или его элемент, как это сделано на основной версии. Будут рад любой подсказке.
[сам сайт](https://niglutenu.com.ua/ru/home)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте и будет вам счастье :)

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    #single_product_page {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В ваш main.css вставьте

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .post_prod_card {
        background-color: transparent
    }
}
```